# numbapro cuda constant global array

Tags: python, numba

I'm using cuda with numbapro and I would like to use a constant global array inside my vectorized function. The example code is here:

```
import numpy as np
from numbapro import cuda, vectorize

stream1 = cuda.stream()
Pxy = np.ones((5,5), dtype='complex128')
Pxy = cuda.to_device(Pxy, stream=stream1)

psi = np.ones((5,5), dtype='complex128')
psi = cuda.to_device(psi, stream=stream1)

@vectorize(['complex128(complex128)'], target='gpu')
def dpsi(psi):
    return Pxy*psi

dpsi(psi)
```

But if tails with this error:

> TypingError: Invalid usage of * with parameters (readonly
>   array(complex128, 2d, C), complex128) Known signatures:  * (int64,
>   int64) -> int64  * (int64, uint64) -> int64  * (uint64, int64) ->
>   int64  * (uint64, uint64) -> uint64  * (float32, float32) -> float32 
>   * (float64, float64) -> float64  * (complex64, complex64) -> complex64  * (complex128, complex128) -> complex128  * parameterized File "vector.py", line 13
>
> Failed at nopython (nopython frontend) Invalid usage of * with
>   parameters (readonly array(complex128, 2d, C), complex12 8) Known
>   signatures:  * (int64, int64) -> int64  * (int64, uint64) -> int64  *
>   (uint64, int64) -> int64  * (uint64, uint64) -> uint64  * (float32,
>   float32) -> float32  * (float64, float64) -> float64  * (complex64,
>   complex64) -> complex64  * (complex128, complex128) -> complex128  *
>   parameterized File "vector.py", line 13

I understand that I could just pass the constant array as an argument, but I wonder if it's possible to use global constant arrays.

Comment: Hamid Ohadi, I am also interested in this questions. Have you find any solution? When I use C I usually apply texture memory in order to store the immutable data for my algorithm. But it seems that numba does not support this type of memory (see 3.1.4. Missing CUDA Features at http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/overview.html)